# refresh iframe upon value change in parent component

Tags: jquery, angular

I have an Angular parent component with a text box and submit button, and a list of child components that serve as tabs. One of the child component tabs displays an HTML iframe. My issue is the following edge case:

1. Load the app
2. Select the HTML tab without entering query -> `ngAfterContentInit()` gets called with empty query
3. Enter query and hit submit button
4. Iframe remains empty, because neither `ngAfterContentInit()` nor `onChange()` got called

How can I fix this behavior? None of the other tabs have this issue because the data there does not require a function call to build the url. Is there a way to rebuild the source url whenever the value of `urlhash` changes?

[image]

Here is the code for the child component, which includes all the code for the content inside the tab, including the checkboxes.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(protected _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  transform(value: string): SafeResourceUrl {
    return  this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-models-sd-htmlview',
  styleUrls: ['./sd.component.scss'],
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="datasource=='CallistoVdom'">
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <div class="widget-container">
        <label class="checkbox-label" style="background-color: rgba(255, 77, 77, 0.6);">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview" (change)="onChange('heading', $event.target.checked)" />
          Heading
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-label" style="background-color: rgba(137, 203, 247, 0.6);">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview" (change)="onChange('paragraph', $event.target.checked)" />
          Paragraph
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-label" style="background-color: rgba(179, 102, 255, 0.7);">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview" (change)="onChange('list', $event.target.checked)" />
          List
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-label" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 60, 0.7);">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview" (change)="onChange('table', $event.target.checked)" />
          Table
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox-label" style="background-color: rgba(255, 173, 51, 0.6);">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview" (change)="onChange('visualtitle', $event.target.checked)" />
          Visual Title
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
    <iframe *ngIf="urlhash" style="width:100%; height:1000px;" [src]="iframe | safe:'iframe'"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="datasource=='OSSemanticDocument'">
    <p>
      This feature is not available for semantic documents pulled directly from ObjectStore. Please use the VDOM from Callisto option.
    </p>
  </div>
  `
})
export class HtmlViewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() urlhash : string;
  @Input() datasource : string;
  // displayedRows$: Observable<any>;  // don't use it  if you don't know about it

  public iframe;
  public checkedAnnotations : FormArray;
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private fb: FormBuilder)
  {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
  };

  ngOnInit()
  {
    console.log("htmlview ngoninit");
    this.form = this.fb.group({name: this.fb.array([])});
    this.checkedAnnotations = (this.form.controls.name as FormArray);
  }

  ngAfterContentInit()
  {
    console.log("htmlview ngAfterContentInit")
    if (this.urlhash!=undefined)
    {
      console.log("htmlview ngAfterContentInit urlhash defined")
      var url = `/sd_api/htmlview/${this.urlhash}/highlighted.html`;
      // this.iframe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
      this.iframe = url;
      console.log(this.iframe);
    }
  }

  // any time a new item is checked or unchecked, add all the checked items
  // to the list and remove all the unchecked items
  onChange(name: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    if (!this.urlhash)
    {
      alert("Query URL cannot be empty!!!");
    }
    else
    {
      if (isChecked) {
        this.checkedAnnotations.push(new FormControl(name));
      } else {
        const index = this.checkedAnnotations.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === name);
        this.checkedAnnotations.removeAt(index);
      }
      var url = `/sd_api/htmlview/${this.urlhash}/highlighted.html?annotypes=${this.checkedAnnotations.value.join()}&datasource=${this.datasource}`;
      console.log(url);
      this.iframe = url;
      // this.iframe = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding the condition `*ngIf="urlhash"` to the child component call.

```
<app-models-sd-htmlview *ngIf="urlhash" [urlhash]="urlhash" [datasource]="datasource"></app-models-sd-htmlview>
```

What this does is prevent `ngAfterContentInit()` from firing in step 2 and instead wait until step 4 to render.